# Отмена синхронизации при создании Raid 1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

При создании Raid 1 массива в ubuntu при помощи mdadm

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
```

после форматирования

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0
```

и монтирования

```
mount /dev/md0 /mnt/newraid
```

началось долгая синхронизация дисков, 2 диска по 6Tb

```
echo 999999 > /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min
```

Диски абсолютно пустые, можно ли как-нибудь отменить или ускорить синхронизацию?

Comment: Создавал 5-й из 3-х винтов по 4тб. Тоже пустые. После создания - был деградирующий массив с пересборкой на 3-й. Почему так - не знаю, но когда пересобрался - пару дней полёт вполне нормальный.

Comment: [это нормально. «ускорять или отменять» просто нечего](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Initial_Array_Creation). @donRumata, там и про raid5 написано.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, пасиба, почитаю.

Answer (score 1):

как написано в [документации](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Initial_Array_Creation), это абсолютно нормальный процесс первоначальной синхронизации.

он приостанавливается для выполнения операций ввода-вывода, и потому создаёт самые минимальные помехи «нормальному» использованию массива.

---

отменять первоначальную синхронизацию (с использованием опции `--assume-clean`) имеет смысл только в двух случаях:

1. если массив уже существовал на этих самых носителях и был всего лишь пересобран после переподключения дисков, а вы абсолютно уверены, что информация в массиве целостна;
2. если вы собираете массив для каких-то тестов и вам не важна целостность помещаемой туда информации.

---

одной фразой: пусть процесс идёт, он вам ничем не мешает.